# RFT Exporting & running it on a server

Tags: java, eclipse, rft

I'm extremely new to rational tools. I have a script recorded and its ready to be exported into something I can execute. I'm not sure how to do so. I'm using Rational Function Tester v 8.1.0.3 Java Scripting. In other words I need  the script to run without Eclipse being open.

Also after I have the script ready to go I need it to run automatically a few times a day automatically on a server, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RFT's command line functionality to kick off scripts. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/run-scripts-through-the-rational-functional-tester-command-line/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a batch file which runs your scripts from Command line arguments , and create a System scheduled task that runs this batch file on a scheduled basis as per your requirement.